# SFML 2.0 Having the same sprite looped

Tags: c++, sfml

I am drawing an invader sprite list into my game using SFML 2.0. At the moment I have to keep copy and pasting my code to draw more sprites in:

```
//load the invaders images
sf::Texture invaders;
sf::Texture invaders2;
sf::Texture invaders3;
sf::Texture invaders4;
sf::Texture invaders5;
sf::Texture invaders6;
invaders.loadFromFile("images/invaders.png");
invaders2.loadFromFile("images/invaders.png");
invaders3.loadFromFile("images/invaders.png");
invaders4.loadFromFile("images/invaders.png");
invaders5.loadFromFile("images/invaders.png");
invaders6.loadFromFile("images/invaders.png");

//Sprites
sf::Sprite invadersSprite(invaders);
sf::Sprite invadersSprite2(invaders2);
sf::Sprite invadersSprite3(invaders3);
sf::Sprite invadersSprite4(invaders4);
sf::Sprite invadersSprite5(invaders5);
sf::Sprite invadersSprite6(invaders6);

invadersSprite2.setPosition(30,NULL);
invadersSprite3.setPosition(60,NULL);
invadersSprite4.setPosition(90,NULL);
invadersSprite5.setPosition(120,NULL);
invadersSprite6.setPosition(150,NULL);

if(Clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds()>REFRESH_RATE)
        {

            //carry out updating tasks
            static float spriteTimer=0.0;  //keep track of sprite time
            spriteTimer+=Clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();

            static int count=0; //keep track of where the sub rect is
            if(spriteTimer>delay)
            {
                invadersSprite.setTextureRect(area);
                invadersSprite2.setTextureRect(area);
                invadersSprite3.setTextureRect(area);
                invadersSprite4.setTextureRect(area);
                invadersSprite5.setTextureRect(area);
                invadersSprite6.setTextureRect(area);
                ++count;
                invadersSprite.move(xVelocity, yVelocity);  
                invadersSprite2.move(xVelocity, yVelocity); 
                invadersSprite3.move(xVelocity, yVelocity); 
                invadersSprite4.move(xVelocity, yVelocity); 
                invadersSprite5.move(xVelocity, yVelocity); 
                invadersSprite6.move(xVelocity, yVelocity); 


if (invadersSprite.getPosition().x >= 770 || invadersSprite2.getPosition().x >= 770 || invadersSprite3.getPosition().x >= 770 || invadersSprite4.getPosition().x >= 770 || invadersSprite5.getPosition().x >= 770 || invadersSprite6.getPosition().x >= 770)// When it hits the right hand side of the screen it will move back down to the left
            {
                xVelocity = left;
                invadersSprite.move(0,down);
                invadersSprite2.move(0,down);
                invadersSprite3.move(0,down);
                invadersSprite4.move(0,down);
                invadersSprite5.move(0,down);
                invadersSprite6.move(0,down);
            } 
            else if (invadersSprite.getPosition().x <= 0 || invadersSprite2.getPosition().x <= 0 || invadersSprite3.getPosition().x <= 0 || invadersSprite4.getPosition().x <= 0 || invadersSprite5.getPosition().x <= 0 || invadersSprite6.getPosition().x <= 0) // When it hits the left hand side of the screen it will move up to the right.
            {
                invadersSprite.move(0,down);
                invadersSprite2.move(0,down);
                invadersSprite3.move(0,down);
                invadersSprite4.move(0,down);
                invadersSprite5.move(0,down);
                invadersSprite6.move(0,down);
                xVelocity = right;
            }
```

Obviously I haven't added all the code to this post, and frankly I don't think it is needed as I just need to show you guys that I am replicating a lot of code just to draw some more sprites. I know that there HAS to be an easier way to do this. I know there is, say if you were creating another game that happened to use a sprite, but 1000 times then I know some poor programmer won't be there doing what I am doing at the moment.

I've been wondering about making an array that holds 10 numbers:

```
int invadersArray[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

and then doing a for loop which loops the rendering of the sprites 10 times, meaning the sprite gets loaded in 10 times. Am I on the right lines here? If I am could I possibly get some help as HOW to do this?

Or perhaps saving the sprite in memory, locating that and then looping that memory location with my array? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're overcomplicating it and not using arrays or containers where you should be. Any time you end up reproducing a variable just with a number at the end of the variable name increasing, it's time to use a container.

Since all of your `sf::Texture`s are exactly the same, you only need to do it once:

```
// Create a texture
sf::Texture invaderTexture;
// Load image file into that texture
invaderTexture.loadFromFile("images/invaders.png");
```

Then, if you want to create, let's say, 10 invader sprites, you would have a container of `sf::Sprite`. Here I show you with a `std::vector`, but other containers (or a plain old array) will work too:

```
// Create a vector of 10 sprites initialised with the texture above
std::vector<sf::Sprite> invaderSprites(10, sf::Sprite(invaderTexture));
```

As you can see, they are all initialised with the same `invaderTexture`. This is much better since you don't need to have a copy of the texture lying around in memory for each invader.

Then you can loop over `invaderSprites` to set their properties:

```
// Loop over the elements of the vector of sprites
for (int i = 0; i < invaderSprites.size(); i++) {
  invaderSprites[i].setPosition(...);
}
```

This should help you get started.

---

To do the same with arrays would look like this for initialisation:

```
// Create an array of 10 sprites (cannot initialise them with textures here)
sf::Sprite invaderSprites[10];
// Loop over each sprite, setting their textures
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  invaderSprites[i].setTexture(invaderTexture);
}
```

Then you can do the same kind of loop whenever you need to do something to all of the invaders.

Comment: Ahh nice. And then I could have something like?

<pre>for (int i = 0; i < invadersSprite; i++) {
            invadersSprite++;
        }<code>

Comment: @JohnathanBrown I may have confused you with some C++11. I'll edit it to be more understandable. You can access `invaderSprites` like an array. `invaderSprites[0]` is the first one, `invaderSprites[1]` is the second. I was assuming you knew about arrays, but if you don't, definitely start reading.

Comment: I do know about arrays, I'm just afraid I'm not very good at programming even though I really like it :(

Comment: @JohnathanBrown Well I've given you a big tip - if you start numbering your variables, you probably need arrays! A `std::vector` is like an array but is much safer and can grow and shrink in size. Experienced C++ programmers tend to use containers (like `std::vector`) over plain old arrays.

Comment: @JohnathanBrown `invaderTexture` is the `sf::Texture` I defined in the first code sample.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I've been doing programming for three days (Obviously with sleep). Perhaps I need a break when I can see this with a clear mind :/ Also, SFML2 doesn't use SetImage? (It can't find it)

Comment: @JohnathanBrown Apologies, I was looking at the wrong documentation. It's `setTexture`.

Comment: @JohnathanBrown I added comments to the code to help explain.

Answer (score 0):

Since `sf::Sprite` keeps a const pointer to the texture you are using, you can reuse the same texture without issue. You are making a lot of textures for no reason when a single one will do. Unfortunately the same doesn't apply to moving the sprites since those are separate objects.

Comment: How would I modify my code to do this? I don't completely understand.

Comment: @JohnathanBrown rather than having 6+ different textures that load the same exact image, just keep a single one. Think of a texture as a spritesheet.