# Can we make an array of sprites in SFML/C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sfml

My question is very simple. Can we make an array of sprites or images in SFML. For example:

```
int myArray[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Consider index number one, two and three are three different images. 
How can we do it? Can anyone explain with some code example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we make arrays or multidimensional arrays of sprites in SFML 2.1/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932939/can-we-make-arrays-or-multidimensional-arrays-of-sprites-in-sfml-2-1-c)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
std::vector<sf::Sprite> myArray;
```

or

```
sf::Sprite myArray[3];
```

Check out the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259771/sfml-2-0-having-the-same-sprite-looped/15259865#15259865). The main part is:

```
// Create a texture
sf::Texture invaderTexture;
// Load image file into that texture
invaderTexture.loadFromFile("images/invaders.png");

// Create a vector of 10 sprites initialised with the texture above
std::vector<sf::Sprite> invaderSprites(10, sf::Sprite(invaderTexture));
```